# Sublime text can't get environment variables in python

Tags: python, environment-variables, sublimetext3

I'm was trying to run the following python code in sublime text

```
import os
os.environ.get("hello")
```

I've set the value of "hello" in my environment variables to `hello world` through the following code in `~/.bashrc` file.

`export hello="hello world"`

When I run this code in sublime it outputs `None` while when I run the same code through terminal using the command `python3 main.py` it outputs the correct value which is `hello world`.

Also, when I open sublime through terminal and run the command `subl`, and when I again run the code in sublime it outputs the correct value.

Is there a way, I can get the correct value of the environment variables without opening sublime through terminal?

Note: I'm running Ubuntu 20.04

Edit: I've figured out the error. There wasn't a problem in script or sublime but instead I've set the environment variables in a wrong way. The environment variables set up in `~/.bashrc` are only limited to the shell. Outside of the shell, they won't work. You I needed to set system-wide variables which can be set up by changing the file `/etc/environment` and adding variables to it in the form of `foo="bar"`.

Comment: your code is correct, but unless you add it in your bashrc file, any new terminal you open won't have the env variable. So, for every new terminal you open you have to `export hello=world`

Comment: I did mention that, I've added the the env variable and was able to get the value by running the code by the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a Python build system to sublime:

Go to Tools / Build System / New Build System and add:

```
{
'cmd': ['/usr/bin/python3', '-u', '$file'],
'file_regex': '^[ ]*File "(…*?)", line ([0-9]*)',
'selector': 'source.python'
}
```

Save the file and then select it in: Tools / Build System

Comment: I've already set up my sublime build system with the exact same code.